# Tuples inside of python string formatting?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting, python-3.5

Basically, I'm trying to templatize Latex code where I need to output strings like `B_{i}`, and I'd like to call string formatting to change `i`. But the problem is that using Python's string formatting - which uses tuples to denote arguments - has been causing me trouble when I want to maintain tuples in my outputted string.

EXAMPLE

Suppose I have:

```
subscript = "22"
value = "10"
stringy = "B_{{0}} = {1}".format(subscript, value)"
```

When I print `stringy` I get:

```
B_{0} = 10
```

I'd like to get:

`B_{22} = 10`

Comment: Escape the characters?

Comment: What does this have to do with tuples? There are no tuples in your code, and `str.format()` does not "use tuples to denote arguments."

Answer (score 2):

```
print("B_{{{0}}} = {1}".format(subscript, value))
```

The `{{` will print out a `{` character in the output, so you need another `{}` to actually access the variable

Answer (score 2):

Double the outer braces to escape those, therefore making a total of 3 pairs:

```
stringy = "B_{{{0}}} = {1}".format(subscript, value)
print(stringy)
# B_{22} = 10
```

As seen in your current solution, the doubled braces `{{...}}` are escaped and do not take part in the formatting. You therefore need to include that extra layer of braces.

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there.  You correctly doubled up the `{` and `}` characters so that they appear literally in the formatted result. However, you now don't have any placeholder for the first value, which needs to be represented as `{0}` in your format string.

So:

```
stringy = "B_{{{0}}} = {1}".format(subscript, value)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need one more pair of curly brackets:

```
subscript = "22"
value = "10"
stringy = "B_{{{0}}} = {1}".format(subscript, value)

print(stringy)  # 'B_{22} = 10'
```

This is because you need double (`"{{"`) to print a literal curly bracket.
The two on the outside print the literal `{}` and the middle `{0}` gets replaced by `subscript`.